# Looking for a method to map Proper nouns into vectors

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, similarity

I'm looking for a method to represent proper nouns into vectors and correct misspellings.

For example, I'd have a database of proper nouns (such as James, Rebecca, Michael, etc...) and would like to map these names into vectors.

I'd also have a set of entries with misspellings of these names (e.g. Rebeca, Mikel etc...) and would like to also map these into vectors.

The objective would be to use a similarity measure between the vector of the misspelled name with each vector of correctly spelled names and identify the correct name.

I cannot find any NLP method which deals with this kind of problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So the goal is spelling correction? And you have no context, just the words? I suggest using kmer distance. That is to say, for suitable values of k, each word is represented by the set of substrings of length k. The distance between words is the sqrt(1-J) where J is the [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) of these sets. Build a nearest neighbour tree of the words. Then the suggested correction is the nearest neighbour of the misspellt word.

You should choose values for k by experiment, but {3,4,5} would be a good starting point.

There are alternatives to the formula sqrt(1-J), but this formula has the advantage that it is the natural metric for the RKHS induced by Jaccard similarity.